# Can the RWIN (TCP Receive Window) be manually set in Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, tcp

Is there a way to manually set the receive window size (RWIN) in Windows Server 2008 R2 after disabling the "Receive Window Auto Tuning" feature?

Comment: It would be interesting to hear why you are disabling auto tuning on 2008.

Comment: @DougLuxem: Not sure if I am going to even do it yet. But see http://serverfault.com/questions/235383/high-instances-of-zero-window-messages .

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it can be manually set, but Microsoft is only exposing it through Socket-Options. Which means specific applications opening sockets can set it, but you can't set it on an adapter like we used to do with Server 2000/2003.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff633467(WS.10).aspx

A big hint on one of the 'best practices analyzer' errors. Apparently the TcpReceiveSize is ignored by 2008R2.

http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/sysperf/Perf_tun_srv.mspx

Down there at the end of the document is a section on doing some tcp testing with Server 2008. They use a specific utility, NTttcp, to do benchmarking. One of the options on that tool is to set window size options.

For IIS, you might be able to set a registry key to tell it to use a different value for that (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820129). I don't know if that works for IIS7 or not.